# How do I prevent resize on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, safari

I have a web app running on Safari on an iPad. I am starting the app from the iPad home page. I want the app to start in full-screen mode, and to continue running in full-screen mode (i.e. not showing the Safari address bar).

I want to prevent the "pinch-to-zoom" and pan/zoom functions so the page always remains static. How do I do this?

Comment: Please stop doing this. It's not accessible.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you put the following meta tag into the html output and then start the app from the homepage then it will be fullscreen when it runs:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

The following is to prevent the user from zooming:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: Thanks  worked a treat. The only thing is, there's still a thin grey bar at the top of the browser (no buttons on it or anything, just plain grey - about 10px high). Any idea if/how I can get rid of that?

Comment: Hmm, can't say since I can't test at the moment. Works fine for me on the new ipad...